# React Router Link is changing URL but the component remains same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So I'm stuck in a problem where when clicking on the Link the URL is changing but the view remains the same until I refresh the page.

I have looked into many solutions and the only thing working is to forcefully reload the page which I don't want as React is a SPA(Single Page Application). I have tried history.push() and Link both but the output remains the same. This is my [repo](https://github.com/YeahItsAman/Rest-Countries-API) if you need to look at other files.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './components/header/header.component';

import HomePage from './pages/homepage/homepage.component';
import Details  from './pages/detail/detail.component';

import './App.scss';

const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
            <Route path="/:name" component={Details}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);
```

**Detail Component**

```
import React from 'react';

import LinkButton from '../../components/link-button/link-button.component';

import './detail.style.scss';

class Details extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            borders: [],
            country: '',
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const { name } = this.props.match.params;
        fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${name}?fullText=true`)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({ country: data[0] });
                return data[0].borders;
            })
            .then((country) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
                    if (i > 2) break;
                    fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${country[i]}`)
                        .then((res) => res.json())
                        .then((data) =>
                            this.setState({ borders: [...this.state.borders, data.name] })
                        );
                }
            });
    }

    render() {
        const { country, borders } = this.state;
        if (country !== '') {
            return (
                <div className="detail-container">
                    <div className="detail-back-btn">
                        <LinkButton value="/">
                            <i className="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left icon"></i> Back
                        </LinkButton>
                    </div>
                    <div className="detail-stats">
                        <img className="detail-flag" alt="Flag" src={country.flag} />
                        <div className="detail-text-container">
                            <h1 className="heading">{country.name}</h1>
                            <div className="detail-text">
                                <div className="left">
                                    <p className="text">
                                        Native Name: <span>{country.nativeName}</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p className="text">
                                        Population:
                                        <span>{country.population.toLocaleString()}</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p className="text">
                                        Region: <span>{country.region}</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p className="text">
                                        Sub Region: <span>{country.subregion}</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p className="text">
                                        Capital: <span>{country.capital}</span>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="right">
                                    <p className="text">
                                        Top Level Domain: <span>{country.topLevelDomain}</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p className="text">
                                        Currencies:{' '}
                                        <span>
                                            {country.currencies.map((e) => e.name).join(', ')}
                                        </span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p className="text">
                                        Languages:{' '}
                                        <span>
                                            {country.languages.map((e) => e.name).join(', ')}
                                        </span>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="border">
                                <p className="border-text">Border Countries:</p>
                                <span className="border-btn">
                                    {borders.map((border, index) => (
                                        <LinkButton key={index} value={border}>
                                            {border}
                                        </LinkButton>
                                    ))}
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        } else return null;
    }
}

export default Details;
```

**LinkButton Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import './link-button.style.scss';

//this is the brute force reload solution
//which is working, but i need a better approach
function refreshPage() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.reload(false);
    }, 0);
    console.log('page to reload');
}

const LinkButton = ({ value, children, history, match, location }) => {
    console.log(history, match, location);
    return (
        <Link to={value} onClick={refreshPage}>
            <button
                className="link-btn"
                value={value}
            >
                {children}
            </button>
        </Link>
    );
};

export default withRouter(LinkButton);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're seeing is a change from one URL to another, but they both match the same `Route` path so `react-router` will not re-mount the component. This is intentional, and also makes sense if you think about the purpose of the `Switch` component.

For example: "/a" and "/b" both match `<Route path="/:name" component={Details}/>`. So when changing from one to another, there's no reason for `react-router` to re-mount the `Details` component because it still matches.

To accomplish what you are trying to do, you will need to listen to updates in the route parameter (the `name` prop).

One strategy for this is to use the [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle method to check if the value has changed:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.match.params.name !== prevProps.match.params.name) {
    // Refetch your data here because the "name" has changed.
  }
}
```

Note that `componentDidUpdate` is not called on the initial render so you will need both lifecycle methods. However, you could pull out your `fetch` call into it's own method so that both your `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` can reuse the same code.

For those using functional components with hooks, this listening process becomes a little easier. Using a `useEffect` hook with the route parameter as the dependency will accomplish the same thing as both lifecycle methods in the class version.

```js
const { name } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  // Fetch data
}, [name]);
```

Comment: thank you so much for giving a detailed solution