# Link redirects to a route but it does not refresh component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using Link in JSX like below

```
<Link to='/dashboard'>Close</Link>
```

This redirect me to `/dashboard` route but it does not refresh dashboard component. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate little further ? There can be multiple scenarios for what you mentioned, what exactly is happening at your end ?

Comment: @arslanshahab I explained it, the link redirects me to the correct route which is `/dashboard` but it does not refresh dashboard component. I want dashboard component to refreshed so it gets up to date data from api.

Comment: @Om3ga you may want to use a life hook or useEffect to watch your component and appropriately fetch data on component mount. 
I would be much easier if you share your implementation.

Comment: Without a MRE we can't answer this.

Comment: Possible duplicate, but can't know for sure with the limited details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67974247/react-router-link-is-changing-url-but-the-component-remains-same/67974377#67974377

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use an `useEffect` in your `dashboard  component`

```js
useEffect(()=> {
// your code…
}, [])
```

Inside the `[]` you can add some dependencies

Comment: This Should Work If You Want Your Component To Display Some Data Upon Rendering.
@om3ga

Answer (score 0):

Okay Firstly Check The PathName You Specified If It Matches The One You Gave To The `<Link to='/dashboard' />` component

In this case the slashes can often be the bug that's causing the issue since it can cause a redirection to another page when not structured well.
check if the slashing structure matches the one in your Router's route component.
 `<Route path='yourUrl' />`

Secondly If it matches then just like @priscilla-joly said.
You need to add a useEffect function if you're using react hooks

```
useEffect(()=> {
// your code…
}, [])
```

or a componentDidMount(){} method if you're using classes.

```
componentDidMount = () =>{
// your code here
}

or 

componentDidMount(){
// your code here
}
```

If you're using `componentDidMount(){ // your code here }`, make sure you bind it first in the class constructor method

Comment: I removed the `/` part but it is still not working. I also used `componentDidMount` but it does not working.

Comment: no i did not ask you to remove the `/` I asked you to crosscheck whether the path structure matches or not.

If it doesn't match, then `componentDidMount` will not work either

Comment: How did you write the path in your route component.
Can you post the full code of your router structure ?